# How to reuse IDs and Names for Select2 Objects

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I have a large table which has One Select2 Object in each row, and they all have a corresponding ID which holds the number of the row they are in.(and they also have the same name) (fmselection1, fmselection2,....)

Whenever the user deletes a row (e.g. with Select2 Object "fmselection2"), I want all subsequent Select2 Objects to decrement their ID and name: 
fmselection3->fmselection2 
fmselection4->fmselection3
...

This is done with reassignment of attributes:

```
$('#fmselection'+i).attr('id', 'fmselection'+(i-1));
$('#fmselection'+(i-1)).attr('name', 'fmselection'+(i-1));
```

This seems to work, but as soon as new rows are again added and activated with

```
$('#fmselection'+newID).select2();
```

The Select2 Object which once used the `newID`suddenly loses its Select2 look, and behaves like a normal HTML select again.

The question I have is:
Does Select2 support "reassigning" IDs and Names at all?

Comment: I think you should first ask yourself what you are using the `id` for in the first place. As you can see, using `id`s can create brittle code that needs fixes like the one you are seeking. There are many other ways to locate and interact with elements besides assigning them unique `id`s.

Comment: You should avoid doing that with `ID`'s, better to use data attribute for example `data-id="3"` etc. Then when you want to do delete and grab the value you can use jQuery function `data()` to get the value like `$(selector).data('id');`

Comment: @penleychan That doesn't really solve the problem. It only moves it to a different attribute. The larger issue is why unique identifiers are needed here in the first place.

Comment: @penleychan this may solve my problem. I will change to a dedicated data attribute instead, see if it works and get back.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my question is **No**, after trying different ways for hours (also with Select("destroy") first and then reactivating), reassigning a formely used ID did not work in both IE and Chrome.

I followed Scott Marcus' approach and tried to avoid the necessity of ID numbering which eventually avoided the reassignment completely.